# How not to overwrite string and put it into typedef function

Tags: c

My output gives the same name and au-ID when I make to enrolledments.
So I think that, when user gives input for secound student it overwrites name and au-ID.

I have tried call the array [i] enstead of [20] and I have tried to use malloc to make to different arrays and make space for them.

```
typedef struct student
{
    char*auID;
    char* name;
    int age;
}student;

int main(void)
{
    //allocate space for student
    int enrolledment = get_int("enrolledment:");
    student students[enrolledment];

    //promt student for name and age and auID
    for(int i=0; i<enrolledment; i++)
    {

         //promt for au-ID
         char getauID[20];
         printf("Enter au-ID: ");
         scanf("%s", getauID);
         students[i].auID=getauID;

        //promt for name
         char getName[20];
         printf("Enter first name: ");
         scanf("%s", getName);
         students[i].name=getName;

        //promt for age
        int getAge;
        printf("Enter age:");
        scanf("%i",&getAge);
        students[i].age=getAge;

    }


    //print students name and age and auID
     for(int i=0; i<enrolledment; i++)
     {
         printf("\n %s is %i and has this au-ID number: %s.\n",students[i].name, students[i].age, students[i].auID);
     }

}
```

I expect the output of to different names and auIDs, when I set enrolledment at 2, but the actual output is only the same name and auID, even when a have entered to different

Comment: This is not C#... maybe C or C++?

Comment: Sorry, I thought C# and C was the same thing.It is written in C

Comment: (let me close my eyes and just guess -- you are using a statically declared array or pointer to take input and you are assigning that to each as you take input -- resulting in all of your elements pointing to the same address which holds the last input you took)? -- yep crystal ball is still working. Note, your code exhibits *Undefined Behavior*, because each variable you declare in the `for` loop goes out of scope at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to take the value given by the user out of the scope and in to the typedef-function ? How would it look, should i just take the pointer from the for loop out of the loop?

Comment: Note: when copying a char/string array, either copy char by char or (better) use the 'string.h' function: 'strcpy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for I/O errors
4. properly outputs error messages to 'stderr'
5. separates, for flexibility. the struct definition from the 'typedef'
6. exits after handling any unrecoverable error
7. since the number of students can not be <0, uses an unsigned value for number of students
8. since the age can not be <0, uses an unsigned age
9. for ease of readability and understanding, incorporates appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing
10. uses the VLA (variable length array) feature of C to declare the length of the array of 'struct student' entries

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fprintf(), scanf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_FIELD_LEN 20

struct student
{
    char auID[ MAX_FIELD_LEN ];
    char name[ MAX_FIELD_LEN ];
    unsigned age;
};
typedef struct student STUDENT;


int main( void )
{
    //allocate space for students
    unsigned enrolledment;
    if( scanf( "%u", &enrolledment ) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number of students failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    // implied else, scanf for number of students successful

    STUDENT students[enrolledment];

    //prompt for  student name and age and auID
    for( unsigned i=0; i<enrolledment; i++ )
    {
        // --> input fields directly into the array entry
        //prompt for au-ID
        printf( "Enter au-ID: " );
        // --> always check for I/O errors and
        // --> limit char array input length
        // --> to one less than the input buffer length
        // --> because '%s' always appends a NUL byte
        if( scanf("%19s", students[i].auID ) != 1 )
        {
            // --> output error messages to 'stderr'
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for auID failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        // implied else, scanf for student ID successful

        //prompt for name
        printf( "Enter first name: " );
        if( scanf("%19s", students[i].name ) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr,  "scanf for name failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        // implied else, scanf for student name successful

        //prompt for age
        printf( "Enter age:" );
        if( scanf( "%u", &students[i].age ) !=1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for age failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        // implied else, scanf for student age successful
    }


    //print students name and age and auID
    for( unsigned i=0; i<enrolledment; i++ )
    {
        // --> honor the right page margin
        printf( "\n %s is %u and has this au-ID number: %s.\n",
                students[i].name, 
                students[i].age, 
                students[i].auID );
    }
}
```

Comment: If we enter more characters than is accepted, the input automatically goes to the next field; that is unexpected.

Comment: The OP indicated the fields only need to be 20 characters long.  However, if that is NOT a valid assumption, then need to insert the following after each input code block:\, similar to: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() ) != '\n' ){;}`

Comment: That's valid, but won't that hang on EOF? I think `fgets` is more suited for interactive terminals.

Comment: @NeilEdelman,  We can think of many situations where some simple bit of code can fail.  However, the objective, here, is to submit a simple bit of code to perform the OPs desired functionality,  The objective is not to make the most robust code possible